# Openstack redundant architecture on three servers

Tags: high-availability, openstack, redundancy, infrastructure

I would like to deploy an Openstack architecture on three (super)servers in a way that if one of server is down the Openstack infrastructure is still functionning.

What is the best way to deploy this ? Is deploying Control, Network and Compute component on each of the three servers the best option ?

On this 3-nodes architecture there is no redudancy as far as I know:

[image]

Thank you for your time

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/beekhof/osp-ha-deploy

Comment: If these are three physical servers you could create three virtual servers on each and run each component on each physical machine. If these are virtual machines the answer below is probably most appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot deploy Control and Compute nodes in the same server for a production environment (only for PoC purposes, like devstack and packstack all-in-one solutions).

Normally, you will have 3 control nodes (control and network nodes), configured with pacemaker for high availability, routers with VRRP using keepalived, etc. Usually control and network can be together, unless your environment grows considerably (a lot), then you will have to consider separate the control and network functions.

Compute nodes must run separatelly. The number of vms you want to run in your environment will define how many compute nodes you will need.